# How to connect with DynamoDB running in Docker Container locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-local

What credentials or configuration should I use to connect to DynamoDB running in a Docker Container locally, through a webapp in Java with Eclipse.

In Java code I  use this:

AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();

Ref: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/use-amazon-dynamodb-local-more-easily-with-the-new-docker-image/

Comment: You need to use endpoint url when defining the DynamoDB object.

Comment: Refer the sample java application which uses the DynamoDB local(Docker) https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-sam-java-rest

Comment: Thanks @krishna_mee2004 now I use ` builderAWS.withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration ("http://localhost:8000", Regions.US_EAST_1.getName())); `  for local test,  

On the other hand, although I have created tables in http://localhost:8000/shell/ but in Java code I got ResourceNotFoundException